# How to display recent posts in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Here is the case, I need the last records of the model to be displayed on the page, for this I added a new pub_date record in the models to add to the queue of records, I also added this to views.py, and it kind of displays, but both records.

views.py code

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

def description(self):
    return self.description_text

def price(self):
    return self.price_text


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    numbers = Number.objects.all()
    context['numbers'] = numbers
    return context

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    avaibilitys = Avaibility.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    context['avaibilitys'] = avaibilitys
    return context
```

models.py code

```
class Avaibility(models.Model):
name_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
apply_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
presence_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.apply_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.presence_text
```

this is what displays[image]

Comment: Does it not word as you intended?

Comment: Hello, I think your question does not make much sense as it stands now.  At least  not to me I cannot understand it. Please provide some more connect or make a dummy example what are your classes where and how are they being called. What class does your get_context_data(() belongs to for example? What is your error exactly?Provide some more info so people can help. Cheers

Comment: @bichanna not it doesn't, I want the last posts to be shown on the page, and both posts are displayed

Comment: @KZiovas I edited the post, do you need more information? or is it full?

Comment: Does the image show the result of `Avaibility` or `Number`?

Comment: @bichanna She results Avaibility

Comment: Please see my answer then.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @bichanna Shows this error 'Avaibility' object is not iterable. Here is the line `{% for avaibility in avaibilitys %}`

Comment: Since you need only one availability, you don't need to loop through anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just sorting the data using `order_by` and assign the sorted data to a variable:

```
avaibilitys = Avaibility.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
```

If you want to get only one of them, you can do this:

```
avaibilitys = Avaibility.objects.order_by('-pub_date').first()
```

**EDIT**

If you want the last one, do this:

```
avaibilitys = Avaibility.objects.order_by('-pub_date').last()
```

Comment: By the way, if anybody wants to get the last object, use `last()`.

Comment: @bichanna Shows this error 'Avaibility' object is not iterable. Here is the line `{% for avaibility in avaibilitys %}`

Comment: You wanted only the first one, right? Or no?

Comment: You said `I need the last records of the model to be displayed on the page`.

Comment: @bichanna No, I need the last entries, not the first